# Некорректная версия OpenGL ES

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengles

Начал новый проект на android ndk с использованием OpenGL ES 2.0 (подключил `GLES2/gl2.h` и `GLES2/gl2ext.h`.

После выполнения всех стандартных действий конфигурации в строке `GL_VERSION` содержится почему-то упоминание версии 1.1, а не 2.0 (что было бы логично).
При запуске приложения выдает в лог Eclipse строчку

> called unimplented OpenGL ES API

хотя приложение из примера с использованием  OpenGL es 2.0 работает корректно, что, я думаю, говорит о том, что аппаратно устройство его поддерживает. 
Как начать использовать OpenGL es 2.0 в этой ситуации?
Версия андроид 4.4.2, lenovo a606